# Keras Tokenizer sequence to text changes word order

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tokenize

I am training a model on DUC2004 and Giga word corpus, for which I am using Tokenizer() from keras as follows:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_of_words) 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(x_train))

#convert text sequences into integer sequences
train_seq    =   tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train) 
val_seq   =   tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_val) 

#padding zero upto maximum length
train_seq    =   pad_sequences(train_seq, maxlen=max_summary_len, padding='post')
val_seq   =   pad_sequences(val_seq, maxlen=max_summary_len, padding='post')
```

When I try to change the sequences back to texts, the word order changes and gives some weird output.

For example:

Actual sentence:

> chechen police were searching wednesday for the bodies of four
> kidnapped foreigners who were beheaded during a botched attempt to
> free them

Sequence to text conversion:

> police were wednesday for the bodies of four kidnapped foreigners who
> were during a to free them

I tried using the sequence_to_text() method of Tokenier() as well as mapping words using the word_index.

I am not able to understand why this happens and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `X_train` should be a list of raw text where each element of this list corresponds to a docuemnt (text). Try below code:

```
x_train = ['chechen police were searching wednesday for the bodies of four kidnapped foreigners who were beheaded during a botched attempt to free them',
        'I am training a model on DUC2004 and Giga word corpus, for which I am using Tokenizer() from keras as follows']

tokenizer = Tokenizer(1000) 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
train_seq = pad_sequences(train_seq, maxlen=100, padding='post')

tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(train_seq)
```

Output:

```
['chechen police were searching wednesday for the bodies of four kidnapped foreigners who were beheaded during a botched attempt to free them',
 'i am training a model on duc2004 and giga word corpus for which i am using tokenizer from keras as follows']
```

Comment: My x_train is a list of raw text. I tried the same code for a smaller number of texts, i.e just couple of sentences. But when I try it on a large corpus, I get this issue. I don’t understand why.

Comment: It works now. I am not sure what was the issue before. I ran the same code again and it works. Maybe the number of words affected the output. But I am not sure. I had put lower number of words than there were in the corpus. Do you think that might have affected it?

Comment: Yes it is due to the low value of `num_words` in the `Tokenizer`. Change it to say `10` and you should again see the messed up `sequences_to_texts`